# In Unity on Android, how can I rotate an object with the accelerometer?

Tags: unity, android, accelerometer

I'm making a game where you control a platform with balls falling on it, and you have to balance the balls and prevent them from falling off. I'm currently using a mouse to control it with this code:

```
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z += Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X");
transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x += Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y");
```

I'm trying to make this an Android app, and want to use motion controls so I can tilt the device, as if it were the platform. I figured I would use the accelerometer for this.

Any ideas on how to do this in Unity?

Comment: Unity wraps the accelerometer. Plenty of [links](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/accelerometer-input) and [examples](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/625540/use-accelerometer-for-roll-a-ball-movement.html)

Comment: Pedantically speaking, rotation of a device is detected using a gyroscope, not an accelerometer (though they are often combined into a single chip).  The former senses angular acceleration, while the latter detects linear acceleration.

Comment: @Sergio I've tried to use the documentation, but it hasn't worked for me. Can you give some sample code?

Comment: @bcrist Most devices don't have a gyro, apparently. My Galaxy S3 apparently does, and some code I wrote with the gyro didn't work. Can you give some code?

Comment: @Chris I've never done any mobile development with Unity; my experience with accel/gyros comes from embedded (microcontroller) programming.  If you don't have a gyro, it can be faked by low-pass filtering the accelerometer output, on the assumption that most of the time, gravity is the only significant force detected.  Even with a gyro, you usually want to combine it with this technique - the gyro is more accurate, but it only detects relative rotation, so it will drift without some absolute reference.

Comment: @Sergio I really need this, can you please give me some more specific guidance? The Unity tutorial worked, but it was for translating an object, not rotating. I've tried just about everything and nothing has worked.

Answer (score 0):

---

**Update:**
As @Philipp mentioned in the comments section, Input.gyro is most likely what you are looking for. But this is a gyroscope if you are looking to use accelerometer then the answer is below. Accelerometer can also be used to determine rotation according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5670134/6603717 .

[Input.gyro](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-gyro.html)

---

```
public class AccelerometerRotation : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 5f;

    private void Update()
    {
        Vector3 accRotation = new Vector3 (Input.acceleration.x, 0.0f, Input.acceleration.y);
        this.transform.Rotate(accRotation * this._speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

[Input.acceleration](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html)

[Transform.Rotate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html)

Comment: According to the documentation, `Input.acceleration` detects device translation. I think what you actually need to detect device rotation is [`Input.gyro.attitude`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-gyro.html). But I usually don't develop mobile games, so I could be wrong about that.